# Chrome incognito and 2-step verification in Gmail

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, verification

Every time I login to Gmail in incognito mode in Chrome on W10 I have to verify 2-step with a code sent to my phone. I don't want to save the login or account details of this G-mail account on my computer. Is there a method to avoid the 2-step verification on a specific Gmail accounts in incognito mode? I have no login problems but it is cumbersome process every time.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows:

- Press "My Google account" for the Gmail in question
- Press "Security"
- Uncheck the box "2-step verification"